# AppCenter Xamarin.iOS app on iOS 16.1 "Unable To Install app."

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios16

I have builded my app Xamarin.iOS with VS for Mac and released via AppCenter but when the app is downloaded and I click on it I can see message "Unable To Install app. This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified. App was firstly built using Ad Hoc provisioning profile with my device added but the issue still occurs. Then I've created new certificate for this app (Enterprise), rebuilt app with this new certificate, released app but again- the same issue. I have also upgraded Xcode to latest version- still the same issue. Even after installing AppCenter profile issue still occurs. I tried few other solution found in internet (rebuild app with another certificate after adding device into ad hoc provisioning profile, check if developer certificate is not expired etc.) but nothing worked...

Have you guys faced similar issue in the past and know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. The problem was with bad configured provisioning profile- I forgot to enable push notifications and associated domain in provisioning profile configuration and this caused there to be inconsistencies between the profile and the entitlements.plist file.